# SilverStripe admin input field masking

Tags: silverstripe, masking

Is there a way to set a mask to an input field in the SilverStripe admin?

Something like:

```
$field = new TextField('name', 'Name');    
$field->setConfig('mask', '##:##');
```

I have searched but could not find anything about this.

Comment: Not that I know of. What HTML do you expect?

Comment: I was just expecting a simple way to do that, and being able to set any kind of mask i want (for money, time, etc)

Comment: There are seperate FormFields for money, date etc. that also take care of validation; masking is currently not supported out of the box, but you can add any attribute you need manually and apply the javascript library of your choice to handle that masking.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't an actual "mask" but you can set the new html5 placeholder attribute like:

```
TextField::create('Name')->setAttribute('placeholder','Name')
```

If you want a very easy jQuery plugin to do masks, this is one I use often: https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/